# Firestore rules do not accept "service" document variable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Today I noticed that the Firestore rules do not accept "service" as a document variable:

Minimal reproduceable example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /mycollection/{service} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Firebase rules bug]

Any other word I've tried/used works. Why?

Comment: Instead of showing just the screenshot, can you also show the minimal, complete rules with which you can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Sure, I've added a minimal reproduceable example.

Comment: I think `service` may be a reserved word, given its use on the top-level. But I can't find a source to validate that claim, so am hoping somebody else can confirm.